# find div containing text and some dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some html in body in which the text is static and the generating span is dynamic on every refresh.

```
<div class="dynamically_generated_class">Your message has been discarded.&nbsp;&nbsp;<!--Static text-->

<!--Dynamically generated span-->
<span class="ag ca" id="link_undo" tabindex="0" role="link" idlink="">
Undo discard</span>
</div>
```

I need to find the class of parent div using `Your message has been discarded.&nbsp;&nbsp;` text.

any help using javascript or jquery will be great.
Thanks...!!!

Comment: just add a span with static id as parrent of your div :) much more easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what are you asking for here... but looks like what you need here is [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

try this

```
 $("div:contains('Your message has been ')").attr('class');
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/5VZY9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    if(divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Your message has been discarded.&nbsp;&nbsp;') != -1)
        results.push(divs[i].className);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
   var classname = $("div:contains('Your message has beendiscarded.&nbsp;&nbsp;')").attr('class');
```